# How to use JavaScript in Perl Object Oriented

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

I am new to Perl CGI Object oriented.

I want to use some javascript in my Perl CGI but I am not able to do that.

I am using Submit button then via param() method I am getting all field parameters.

But I want to validate all fields first then I want to move. But Use of Java script, I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Javascript used in webpages run on the client (in the browser) not on the server.

- [What is JavaScript](http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/p/javascript.htm)
- [JavaScript: Use in webpages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Use_in_web_pages)

Comment: Javascript is used serverside nowadays.

Comment: @alfa64:Yes it is, since at least 15 years, but not when embeded in html page.